# Connection timed out after exposing external IP in GCP

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, gcp-load-balancer

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPBSd.png)

I am trying to deploy my ML pipeline on kubernetes using GCP but after exposing IP I am getting connection timeout and same with curl cmd added firewall for port tried checking logs facing this issue.
PS:- https://towardsdatascience.com/deploy-machine-learning-model-on-google-kubernetes-engine-94daac85108b (referred this blog and updated versions with latest in requirements.txt still facing the issue)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZrX.png)

expected this page to be loaded

Comment: The image with the error indicates the pycaret is not installed on the docker image. If you are following the medium blog, check the step "Step 4— Build the docker image" and observe the build logs and note if package are getting installed inside the image.

Comment: I tried checking https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=us-west1?referrer=search&project=universal-valve-407216 for build logs couldn't find any could you please tell where it is located thank you

Comment: while running the build step in cloud shell, typically you can see the build steps on terminal, if not, you can run with verbosity in build https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference#--verbosity and notice the logs

Comment: couldn't find logs in terminal so did "docker logs gcr.io/universal-valve-407216/insurance-app" and got "Error response from daemon: No such container: gcr.io/universal-valve-407216/insurance-app" so did pip freeze which showed pycaret==3.2.0